# Graficar con un formato en Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib

Tengo el Siguiente DataFrame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("D:/Data Mangrove Tower - copia/Campbell 1/CR3000-MangroveTower_Table1.csv")

x1 = df.iloc[:,0]
y1 = df.iloc[:,1]
plt.xlabel('x1')
plt.xlabel('y1')
plt.plot(x1,y1,'b-')
plt.title('Datos')

plt.show()
```

Dos preguntas:

1. Solo quisiera graficar las **dos columnas** pero cuando en la **primera columna sea del dia 23/8/16**. Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?.
2. Como hacer para que la grafica tome forma de una linea continua. ya que con **b-** me salen en lineas entrecortadas.

Procedí a sustituir:

'data = io.StringIO("""\ TOA5 TIMESTAMPS TS,CR3000-MangroveTower RECORD RN 22/8/16 11:30,900 23/8/16 12:40,925 23/8/16 12:50,926 23/8/16 13:20,900 23/8/16 13:50,912 23/8/16 14:30,985 23/8/16 14:45,996 23/8/16 14:50,915 23/8/16 15:10,926 23/8/16 15:50,912 24/8/16 12:30,974 24/8/16 12:40,963 24/8/16 13:50,989 25/8/16 14:40,925 25/8/16 15:50,926 """)'

por:

'data = pd.read_csv('D:/Data Mangrove Tower - copia/Campbell 1/CR3000-MangroveTower_Table1.csv')'

y me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Copié el código tal cual:

A la izquierda el código, a la derecha la ejecución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, la verdad cuando evaluo el tipo de dato _type(22/8/16 12:40)_ me sale error.

cuando evaluo _type(22/8/16)_ me sale que es tipo **float**

y cuando evaluo _type(12:40)_ me sale error.

No se si debería separarlo de columnas o asignarle un tipo de variable a esa columna. 

Lo importante es que la fecha y la hora me quede en el eje X y la otra columna en el eje Y.

Bueno... si solo me queda la opcion de eliminar las horas, no me quedara de otra.

Comment: Por cierto, no especificas como quieres que se vean las etiquetas del eje x, en este caso uso explícitamente como marcas las fechas del df y se muestran las horas solo, pero se puede modificar como desees. Desde mostrar también la fecha, rotarlas,  mostrar las marcas cada x horas o minutos en vez de usar las del dataframe explícitamente, etc

Comment: @FJSevilla para mi seria mucho mejor

Comment: Quiero que en le eje **X**, salga el día y la hora, y en el eje **Y**, salgan los valores que esten en la columna de la derecha.

Comment: ¿Solo el dia "22 - 12:40" o la fecha completa "22/8/16 12:40"? En cuanto al eje x, en vez e aparecer una escala como en mi ejemplo quieres que parezcan los valores exactos que hay en la columna? ¿Igual que hago con el eje y?

Comment: La fecha Completa **22/8/16 12:40** en el eje **X** y el eje **Y** puede estar a escala, no necesariamente lo deseo con los valores exactos.

Comment: Editada la respuesta, mira al final. Por cierto, el último error que muestras al usar mi código es porque se me escapó una "s" en el nombre de la columna, tenía "TOA5 TIMESTAMP**S** TS" en vez e "TOA5 TIMESTAMP TS", corregido. De cualquier forma asegurate que los nombres de las columnas coinciden con los de tu csv.

Answer (score 2):

Lo más simple para filtrar mediante la columna con las fechas es hacer que esta sea de tipo `DateTime` y que además sea el índice de tu DataFrame (`DateTimeIndex`).

Para parsear tu columna de fechas solo tienes que indicar a `pandas.read_csv` la columna o columnas que quieres que sean convertidas a `Datetime` mediante el argumento `parse_dates`. Dado que tu columna con las fechas tiene una estructura estándar no tienes que especificar un parser, pero si tienes que indicar que el día está antes que el mes mediante el argumento `dayfirst`.

Hecho esto obtener solo las filas que quieres es tan simple como usar la cadena representando la fecha para filtrar con `loc`, es decir:  `df.loc["23/08/2016"]`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


data = io.StringIO("""\
TOA5 TIMESTAMP TS,CR3000-MangroveTower RECORD RN
22/8/16 11:30,900
23/8/16 12:40,925
23/8/16 12:50,926
23/8/16 13:20,900
23/8/16 13:50,912
23/8/16 14:30,985
23/8/16 14:45,996
23/8/16 14:50,915
23/8/16 15:10,926
23/8/16 15:50,912
24/8/16 12:30,974
24/8/16 12:40,963
24/8/16 13:50,989
25/8/16 14:40,925
25/8/16 15:50,926
""")

df = pd.read_csv(
    data,
    parse_dates=["TOA5 TIMESTAMP TS"],
    dayfirst=True,
    index_col="TOA5 TIMESTAMP TS"
)

plot_data  = df.loc["2016-08-23", "CR3000-MangroveTower RECORD RN"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_data.plot(ax=ax, style='b-')

ax.set_xlabel('y1')
ax.set_title('Datos')
ax.set_xticks(plot_data.index)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ha usado `io.StringIO` para emular un fichero csv, en tu caso cambia el argumento `data` de `pd.read_csv` por la ruta al tu fichero.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates



df = pd.read_csv(
    "D:/Data Mangrove Tower - copia/Campbell 1/CR3000-MangroveTower_Table1.csv",
    parse_dates=["TOA5 TIMESTAMP TS"],
    dayfirst=True,
    index_col="TOA5 TIMESTAMP TS"
)

plot_data  = df.loc["2016-08-23", "CR3000-MangroveTower RECORD RN"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_data.plot(ax=ax, style='b-')

ax.set_xlabel('y1')
ax.set_title('Datos')
ax.set_xticks(plot_data.index)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

plt.show()
```

---

### Edición

Para mostrar también la fecha en el eje x solo hay que especificar el formato de forma correcta de acuerdo a los códigos de formato aceptados:

- [Python datetime. Códigos de formato](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

quedaría así:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y %H:%M'))
```

con lo que las fechas se mostrarían de la forma:

> 22/8/16 12:40